# How to correctly enable ANSI colors in ConEmu + Git Bash?

Tags: git-bash, conemu, color-codes, ansi-colors

I'm using [Git Bash](http://git-scm.com/downloads) with [ConEmu](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/) to make it look cool. However, upon installing Composer the colors seem to be escaped:

[image]

So Git Bash does not support all the colors. Checking the AnsiColors256.ans file:

[image]

After lots of Googling, I still haven't found any solution. I don't want to use Ansicon or other console emulator, ConEmu is fine for me.

My settings:

- Inject ConEmuHk enabled
- Ansi X3.64 / xterm 256 enabled
- Windows 7 x64
- Git Bash 1.9.5
- ConEmu 141208

**How do I enable all the colors? This is annoying my need for a Console-Zen experience :(**

Comment: Composer? Git-bash? They are absolutely different applications.

Comment: Sure, but seems more like a console issue to me. Even [in Composer's setup file](https://getcomposer.org/installer) it says ANSI color output should work in Ansicon and ConEmu. (first couple of lines)

Comment: **UPDATE:** Running `php -r "echo getenv('ConEmuANSI');"` in ConEmu says `ON`

Comment: Found an [old issue](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/issues/detail?id=1030). Seems like it is a bug in ConEmu.

Comment: It is *not* a ConEmu bug! Ansi is working properly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To correctly enable colors in Git Bash :

1. Download and extract **ANSICON** : https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon/releases/tag/v1.81
2. If you are running ***64-bit OS***, copy everything inside ***x64*** folder, Otherwise,

   - If you are running ***32-bit OS***, copy everything inside ***x86*** folder.
3. Create a folder **ANSICON** at **C:\Program Files\ANSICON** and paste the copied contents here.
4. Right click on your **Git Bash shortcut** and go to **properties**.

[image]

5. Set/Modify **Target** value to following (refer to the screenshot below) :

> "C:\Program Files\ANSICON\ansicon.exe" "C:\Program
>   Files\Git\git-bash.exe" --cd-to-home

[image: Modify shortcut target]

6. Open your **.bashrc** file (C:\Users\Aditya\.bashrc).

> **NOTE:** .bashrc is a hidden file. So you need to turn on the option in your windows explorer settings to display hidden files.

7. Add following 2 lines to your .bashrc file (anywhere) :

> unalias $(alias | grep winpty | grep php | cut -d"=" -f1 | cut -d" "
>   -f2)
>
> export ANSICON=true

[image]

8. Save your **.bashrc** file and open Git Bash now. Done!
   [image: composer command output]
   [image: php artisan colored output - very tricky to get]

Comment: This also works with Console2 or its fork Consolez, just like Aditya showed with the shortcut target : in console2 tabs settings, prepend the "shell" setting for the git bash tab with the path to ansicon.exe

Comment: Windows Defender shows ANSICON v1.81.zip as containing Trojan:Win32/Tiggre!plock

Comment: I had to create .bashrc by my self and the git bash automatically created .bash_profile and now it is working just the way it should

Comment: Seems like there should be `-a` option: `unalias -a $(alias | grep winpty | grep php | cut -d"=" -f1 | cut -d" " -f2)`

Answer (score 4):

Run ConEmu from <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> (type full path to sh.exe if needed)

```
ConEmu -basic -cmd sh.exe -l -i
```

Run `composer`, ANSI is working.

[image: ANSI is working]

Comment: Thanks! Don't know that the -l and -i flags do but managed to make it work! It now displays correct colours.

Comment: The `-l` and `-i` flags make it work because you're telling bash to run a "login" and "interactive" shell, respectively. "login" is needed if you want it to run your `.bashrc` file, "interactive" tells bash it will read from and write to a terminal; without a terminal, it won't enable colorization. Further details as the [GNU bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Invoking-Bash.html)

(in reply to @WillSolo)

Answer (score 1):

Another problem you may encounter is if you set up the task (Settings → Startup → Tasks) without proper quoting. Having a task like the following will break ANSI coloring of composer (everything else seems to work just fine):

```
%TOOLS_DIR%\git\bin\sh.exe --login -i -new_console:C:%TOOLS_DIR%\git\mingw64\share\git\git-for-windows.ico:t:"Git bash"
```

The value of `%TOOLS_DIR%` is `D:\Tools`. I can only imagine that the backslashes are the problem. however, the following works as expected:

```
"%TOOLS_DIR%\git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i -new_console:C:"%TOOLS_DIR%\git\mingw64\share\git\git-for-windows.ico":t:"Git bash"
```