# Command line is formatting lines wrong

Tags: git, bash, command-line-interface

Recently I decided to install git-up (https://github.com/msiemens/PyGitUp)

However the program seems to have some weird behaviour when it comes to displaying text. It gives nearly every character a prefix: `<--[0m` or `<--1m`. I have seen this kind of behaviour in other bash programs as well.

[image: This is the example I am talking about.]

Somewhere I read this has something to do with color formatting, however I cannot find a way to fix this.

Comment: you can see [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/10065/111273) how to check if your terminal supports color printing

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27580668/how-to-correctly-enable-ansi-colors-in-conemu-git-bash

Comment: @YuriG. he is probably on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [mention here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16799175/6309) and in this [blog post](http://www.liferay.com/web/igor.spasic/blog/-/blogs/enable-ansi-colors-in-windows-command-prompt), you can try and install [**`adoxa/ansicon`**](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon).

Install it with: `ansicon -i`

It should allow Windows console to interpret correct ANSI colors.

[image: http://cdn.www.liferay.com/image/image_gallery?uuid=0fb11df9-88f5-4b52-94ee-3dbe2577fc44&groupId=4895702&t=1334439795078]