# Git Bash console output breaks down when using Laravel Console choice method

Tags: windows, git-bash

I've a little problem with my console. When I use `choice` method from *Laravel Console*, the output totally breaks down. I wanted to google this but I can't find any solution. It's really annoying.

Anyone know how to fix this?

I'm using **Git Bash** provided by Git for Windows.
That Git bash is an emultion of unix console and it makes me able to use unix like commands. I don't want to stop using this.

Here is the console output

> Give your group a name:
>
> > Something
>
> Give your group a description (blank for skip):
>    >
>
> Do you want to assign scopes to your new group? (y/n):
>
> > y
>
> Select existing scope name:   [0] Random   [1] Exit (It's not a
>   scope)
>
> > 0 0?[K
>
> ?[32mSelect existing scope name?[39m:   [?[33m0?[39m] Random
>   [?[33m1?[39m] Exit (It's not a scope)
>    >

And the php code as below.

```
$name = $this->ask('Give your group a name');

$description = $this->ask('Give your group a description (blank for skip)');

$groups = app()->make(ScopeGroupRepository::class);

/** @var ScopeGroup $group */
$group = $groups->perform(new Create($name, $description));

$willCreateScopes = $this->answerToBoolean(
    $this->ask('Do you want to assign scopes to your new group? (y/n)')
);

if(!$willCreateScopes) {
    return $this->displayCreatedGroupInfo($group);
}

$scopes = app()->make(ScopeRepository::class);

/** @var Collection $unassigned */
$unassigned = $scopes->perform((new ShowAllUnassignedToGroup())->setGroupId($group->id));

if($willCreateScopes) {
    do {
        $scopes = $unassigned->map(function (Scope $scope){
            return $scope->id;
        })->toArray();

        array_push($scopes, 'Exit (It\'s not a scope)');
        // Here it breaks down
        $selected = $this->choice('Select existing scope name', $scopes);

    } while($selected !== 'Exit (It\'s not a scope)');
}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27580668/how-to-correctly-enable-ansi-colors-in-conemu-git-bash/48206769#48206769

Comment: So I should install ConEmu to make it work properly?

Comment: I honestly have no idea. I came here because some keeps tagging the question with php, laravel, and git, and this has nothing to do with any of those things. It's a windows + GitBash ANSI color issue.